# After Upgrading to lollipop, pattern lock issue, after unlock again screen locks , very annoyinig

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have upgraded my Moto G2 phone set to Lollipop version, After I did this facing issue with screen pattern lock/unlocking.

After I unlock screen, it goes lock again and this continues until I frustrated and I leave my phone untouched for sometime. Then I try after some time should be ok.

Very annoying and making life complex when desperately need to use.

Please some one share if you have face similar issue and resolved. Thanks.

Cheers
Sankar

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts StackExchange. Please be clearer asto what the problem really is...

Comment: Seems clear enough to me -- the device is repeatedly locking itself when it is unlocked.

Comment: Possibly, Remove lock screen option immediately when phone screen turns off, if its enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is dumb... but are you using flip cover. I had similar problem with my oneplus one recently and in the oneplus one forums they say that this is caused by the magnet in the flip cover. When you fold it back it falsely triggers the locking mechanism it seems. Although i agree to this i don't know how it wakes after sometime!!